# Recreating ExecutorService in the loop for batch processing

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, executorservice

Example: I need to process millions of records, I want to process them in parallel to speed up processing. For that purpose, I want to use the thread pool within Executor Service. Every task take max a few seconds. To not create million of threads for each record within one thread pool, which in my case led to memory issues, I decided to process records in batches.

I want to use for each batch a new thread-pool. I make Executor Service wait until batch tasks finished and then I will shutdown Executor Service and create a new one to process the next batch. 
I do something like this:

```
/*...................*/
int count = 1;
ExecutorService executor = buildExecutor(CORE_THREADS, MAX_THREADS);
            while (/* there is a record */) {
                executor.execute(new ProcessRecordThread(record));
                count++;
                if (count % BATCH_SIZE == 0) {
                    executor.shutdown();
                    executor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
                    executor = buildExecutor(CORE_THREADS, MAX_THREADS);
                }
            }
 /*................*/
```

Method to create Executor Service

```
private static ExecutorService buildExecutor(int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize) {
            return new ThreadPoolExecutor(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, 0L,
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                    new LinkedBlockingQueue(),
                    Executors.defaultThreadFactory());
        }
```

I know that creating a thread pool adding some overhead to processing. It is considered bad practice to create executor service in the loop. Are there any trade-offs I should be aware of?

Its there any way how to achieve this behavior just by using one thread pool?

Comment: What is the point of recreating the executor here? Why not just use the same one?

Comment: otherwise, it creates millions of threads in one thread pool, and it runs to heap memory issues. At least with basic JVM setup

Answer (score 0):

Build class has one static common dataSource like `C3P0`(open source) in singleton pattern to manage connection.

config `c3p0.maxPoolSize = x` and run x threads to get connection from dataSource then execute sql.

#### example:

```java
public class C3P0Pool {
    private static ComboPooledDataSource CPDS = new ComboPooledDataSource("c3p0");
    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        return CPDS.getConnection();
    }
    public static DataSource getDataSource() {
        return CPDS;  // QueryRunner could constructed with DataSource
    }
}
```

You dont have to shutDown dataSource,connection would return to dataSource while execute `connection.close()`.

Comment: I am not making a connection to a database or running any sql. a million records could be lines from the file

Comment: oops...sry. then，why recreating the ThredPool here?try Es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(num) and set allowCoreThreadTimeOut=true。thread would return to ThreadPool when his job finished。you just need to es.execute(Runnable command)

Comment: and there is a idea to use ThreadPoolTaskExecutor in SpringBoot，but i'm not well realize it at this moment，you could try then

Comment: i think you should detect the workQueue(like LinkedBlockingQueue) per second and put in task with schedule for avoiding chock up the workQueue